# PHP Generate Array based on Value Frequency

Tags: php, arrays, frequency-distribution

I'm trying to understand the best way to build an ordered array of values based on a frequency in which they should occur. Resulting array could have zero to some repeating characters, based on the characters' frequency and ordering isn't relevant. Here's a breakdown of example data:

Character Frequencies

```
a => 0.05
b => 0.05
c => 0.1
d => 0.1
e => 0.2
f => 0.5
```

Result Examples:

```
['b', 'd', 'a', 'f']
['f', 'f', 'c', 'a']
['e', 'c', 'a', 'f']
['a', 'e', 'f', 'd']
```

The math certainly isn't accurate here; it's just to demonstrate the previous statements. I'm *not* concerned with the order of arrays and some *may* have repeating characters.

Here's a basic loop building the array. The contrived `rand()` method here is to spare this post all the different outrageous math methods I've tried in effort to keep the question direct and merely conceptual.

```
$frequencies = [
    'a' => 0.05,
    'b' => 0.05,
    'c' => 0.1,
    'd' => 0.1,
    'e' => 0.2,
    'f' => 0.5
];

$characters = 'abcdef';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    // $result[] = $this->getCharacterByFrequency();
    $result[] = $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be cool to see if anyone has a more efficient way of doing this. I'm sure one exists.

```
$frequencies = [
    'a' => 0.05,
    'b' => 0.05,
    'c' => 0.1,
    'd' => 0.1,
    'e' => 0.2,
    'f' => 0.5
];

$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
    $r = mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax();
    foreach ($frequencies as $letter => $frequency) {
      $r -= $frequency;
      if ($r < 0) break;
    }
    $result[] = $letter;
}
```

I tested the code with 100000 results and got accurate results.

```
array (size=6)
'a' => float 0.0503105
'b' => float 0.0496805
'c' => float 0.099721
'd' => float 0.100001
'e' => float 0.201242
'f' => float 0.499055
```